# Underlying elements are getting clicked on "touchstart" jquery event of li above in Ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, touch

I have a dropdown **li**'s having greater z-index than underlying elements which is suppossed to catch **touchstart jquery** event. But instead underlying elements are getting clicked.
I also tried to alert() **touchstart** event, but alert is not happening.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are testing on a device, using a mouse, in which case mousedown events are triggered, rather than touchstart.  Some code that might be useful to make things more device independent: `isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;` and then (in jQuery): `$(element).bind('click',false).bind(isiPad?'touchstart':'mousedown',function(e){...`

Comment: No, then the underlying elements wouldn't be triggered either... so scratch that...